# Get URL of ASP.Net Page in code-behind from another page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to find away to determine a pages url from the page object. It seems you can only get the path of the current context.

Answer (score 2):

A page can have several urls.  For example, I have a server running at home and the site's url is different depending on where I check it from.  When I'm at home I just use the internal server name so that the traffic never leaves my home network.  When I'm elsewhere I have to use the dyndns.org -based url.  I could also configure several different sites to all point to the same place.  The point is that this information is not tied to your page's class type, or even a specific instance.

Therefore, the URL of a page can only be determined on a per-request basis, and sure enough you can get it by looking at [`Request.Url`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url.aspx)

Comment: the per request thing is my problem. I can always get it in context but I would like just to get the script path either virtually (for web) or physically (on the disk).  I don't actually need the full url just the directory and script location

Comment: My advise is to add that path as a parameter for whatever function needs it, and change how you call it.

Comment: Hmm... I take part of it back.  It's per session rather than per-request.  The logic involved (and proposed solution) still apply, however.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully one of these will help you.

[Understanding Paths in ASP.NET](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101145)

Expression - Evaluation

this.TemplateSourceDirectory - /informit/subdir

Request.MapPath("log.txt") - c:\mywebdirs\informit\subdir\log.txt

this.MapPathSecure("log.txt") - c:\mywebdirs\informit\subdir\log.txt

Request.Path - /informit/subdir/pathsample.aspx/extra

Request.FilePath - /informit/subdir/pathsample.aspx

Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath - /informit/subdir/pathsample.aspx

Request.PathInfo - /extra

Request.PhysicalPath - c:\mywebdirs\informit\subdir\pathsample.aspx

Request.PhysicalApplicationPath - c:\mywebdirs\informit\

Request.ApplicationPath - /informit

Request.Url - http://localhost/informit/subdir/client.aspx/extra

Request.RawUrl - /informit/subdir/pathsample.aspx/extra

Response.ApplyAppPathModifier("foo.aspx") - /informit/subdir/foo.aspx

this.ResolveUrl("~/client.aspx") - /informit/pathsample.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It should be available via

`string currentUrl = Page.Request.Url.ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

If the page you are seeking is in the same directory as the current page, or a subdirectory of it, then you can use something like the following (adding the sub-directory page into the string, as needed):

```
string targetUrl =  HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme
                 + "://"
                 + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority
                 + this.TemplateSourceDirectory + "/Page.aspx";
```