# C# get current URL of webform

Tags: c#, webforms

I'm trying to check the current web address of a webform.

I'm currently navigating to this new page by

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id").InvokeMember("click");
```

I would like to get the url from the form, I know I could do this by a web browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the URL of the current page in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593709/how-to-get-the-url-of-the-current-page-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get URL of ASP.Net Page in code-behind from another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651127/get-url-of-asp-net-page-in-code-behind-from-another-page)

Answer (score 0):

Handle `DocumentCompleted` event of `WebBrowser` and check `Url` propertty of `WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

So are you doing this in WinForms or Web Forms?

It looks like the former, so, to get the URL or `action` attribute value from a `<form>` using a `WebBrowser` would be the following:

```
    var form = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ID");
    var actionurl = form.GetAttribute("action");
```

But, if you literally want the URL of the document, then it's just:

```
var url = webBrowser1.Document.Url;
```